# How to edit List Hover Background color in Vscode theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using **VSCODE**, I would like to know what is the setting to change the **background color** that I point to with a yellow arrow in the following image.

[image]

It is in a gray that I hardly perceive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `list.hoverBackground`

You can update it by adding the following settings to your settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.hoverBackground": "#000", // add your color of choice here 
}
```